# SQL Function "declare scalar variable"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was creating a T-SQL function, and I got an error:

> Must declare scalar variable @UserId

Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AccountsOfTheUser
(@UserId INT)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURNS 
(
   SELECT 
      dbo.accounts.account_id, dbo.accounts.account_name, 
      dbo.account_type.description, dbo.users.user_name, dbo.users.first_name, 
      dbo.users.midle_name, dbo.users.email, dbo.account_type.type_name
   FROM 
      dbo.accounts 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.account_type ON dbo.account_type.type_id = dbo.accounts.type_id 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.users ON dbo.accounts.user_id = dbo.users.user_id
  WHERE 
      (dbo.accounts.user_id = @UserId)
);
```

Comment: `AS RETURNS` should be `AS RETURN` aside from that it looks ok for mssql

Comment: @AlexK. make that an answer?

Comment: Though the error message you get when you execute that is `Incorrect syntax near 'RETURNS'`. I presume `Must declare scalar variable @UserId` is shown in intellisense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AccountsOfTheUser
(@UserId INT)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
SELECT dbo.accounts.account_id, dbo.accounts.account_name,        dbo.account_type.description, dbo.users.user_name, dbo.users.first_name, 
            dbo.users.midle_name, dbo.users.email, dbo.account_type.type_name
FROM dbo.accounts INNER JOIN
            dbo.account_type ON dbo.account_type.type_id = dbo.accounts.type_id INNER JOIN
            dbo.users ON dbo.accounts.user_id = dbo.users.user_id
  WHERE (dbo.accounts.user_id = @UserId)
 );
```

Comment: Thank you... and sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AccountsOfTheUser
(@UserId INT)
RETURNS TABLE
BEGIN  
    RETURN (SELECT ...)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Only issue I see off hand is the second `RETURNS` that should be `RETURN`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AccountsOfTheUser
(@UserId INT)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
```